# migrate ftFloat type Delphi RIO

Tags: delphi, dataset, field, delphi-10.3-rio

I have an application in delphi 5 and I'm trying to migrate it to delphi RIO. 
I have problem whaen getting float value,

in getFieldData i have this code :

```
if Buffer <> nil Then
begin
  case Field.DataType of
    ftFloat :
    begin
      //ShowMessage((FieldText));
      PInt64(Buffer)^:= StrToint(FieldText);
    end;
end;
```

in my exemple FieldText = '3', and NUMSEQ is my float field

When I try to get Dataset1.FieldByName('NUMSEQ').AsString , I have a weired results like this : 
3,50970580934475E-33

Any one can help me pls ... 
and thanks in advance.. 
(sorry for my bed english)

Comment: What type of database are you using? What about the drivers?

Comment: hello Jerry, I'm using Customer Information Control System(CICS) to access to DB2 database

Comment: Is your compilation target 32-bit or 64-bit?  And why are you writing your own GetFieldData?

Comment: That's not a *weird* result. That's the floating point value in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Comment: That code in `GetFieldData` for `ftFloat` looks very defect to me fwiw. Debug through the `AsString` (I would guess the field is a `TFloatField`) to see how it retrieves its binary data from the dataset buffer and interprets it in order to fix it.

Comment: Hello, I resolve my problem like this : PDouble(Buffer)^:= StrToint(FieldText);